# Exclude Substring from Match

Tags: regex, string, match

This Regex is written with the .Net Regex Class.

So I have this string:

```
<div style="text-align:center;font-size: 18px;"><span style="font-size:14px;">11th of April 2015</span> 18:10</div>
```

I have this Regex Code:

```
[0-9]{1,2}(st|nd|rd|th) of \w{3,9} \d{4}<\/span> \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}
```

This Code return this Match:

```
11th of April 2015</span> 18:10
```

Is there a possibility with Regex to exclude the

```
(st|nd|rd|th) of
```

and

```
</span>
```

from the Match to make it look like this:

```
11 April 2015 18:10
```

I have tried with positive lookbehind, but I didn't get it to work.

Comment: use html parser instead?

Comment: Is it JavaScript you are using?

Comment: No I am using C# Regex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use grouping for sub-string that you want and [*none capturing*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) for the groups that you don't want:

```
(\d+)(?:st|nd|rd|th) [a-zA-Z]+ ([a-zA-Z]+) (\d+)<\/span>\s?(\d+:\d+)<\/div>
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rS4bB3/2)

Comment: This results in `11`, `April`, `2015` being captured. In OP, it is stated that `11 April 2015 18:10` must be the final result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [non-capture group](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#noncapturing_group): `(?:...)`

Answer (score 0):

You can match the parts of the string that you need, and then combine the capture groups, e.g.:

```
var regex34 = new Regex(@"([0-9]{1,2})(?:(?:st|nd|rd|th) of)( \w{3,9} \d{4})<\/span>( \d{1,2}:\d{1,2})");
var input34 = "<div style=\"text-align:center;font-size: 18px;\"><span style=\"font-size:14px;\">11th of April 2015</span> 18:10</div>";
var result = regex34.Match(input34);
var final = result.Groups[1].Value + result.Groups[2].Value + result.Groups[3].Value;
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: @Encore: I gave the correct answer with testing results in VS2012 first.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I had the C# code already and just needed the new Regex, that was first provided by Kasra. Sorry!